# Regarding the workings of cookies in sign in systems on the web

Tags: http, cookies, web

I was using Fiddler see on-the-field how web sites use cookies in their login systems. Although I have some HTTP knowledge, I'm just just learning about cookies and how they are used within sites.

Initially I assumed that when submitting the form I'd see no cookies sent, and that the response would contain some cookie info that would then be saved by the browser.

In fact, just the opposite seems to be the case. It is the request that's sending in info, and the server returns nothing.

When fiddling about the issue, I noticed that even with a browser cleaned of cookies, the client seems to always be sending a RequestVerificationToken to the server, even when just looking around withot being signed in.

Why is this so?

Thanks

Comment: You're asking a general question, but describing specific behavior. RequestVerificationToken is asp.net I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are set by the server with the `Set-Cookie` HTTP response header, and they can also be set through JavaScript.

A cookie has a path.  If the path of a cookie matches the path of the document that is being requested, then the browser will include all such cookies in the `Cookie` HTTP request header.

You must make sure to be careful when setting or modifying cookies in order to avoid XSS attacks against your users.  As such, it might be useful to include a hidden and unique secret within your login forms, and use such secret prior to setting any cookies. Alternatively, you can simply check that HTTP `Referer` header matches your site.  Otherwise, a malicious site can copy your form fields, and create a login form to your site on their site, and do form.submit(), effectively logging out your user, or performing a brute-force attack on your site through unsuspecting users that happen to be visiting the malicious web-site.

The `RequestVerificationToken` that you mention has nothing to do with HTTP Cookies, it sounds like an implementation detail that some sites written in some specific site-scripting language use to protect their cookie-setting-pages against XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit a page on a website, usually the response(the page that you landed on) contains instructions from the server in the http response to set some cookies.

Websites may use these to track information about your behavior or save your preferences for future or short term.

Website may do so on your first visit to any page or on you visit to a particular page.

The browser would then send all cookies that have been set with subsequent request to that domain.

Think about it, HTTP is stateless. You landed on Home Page and clicked set by background to blue. Then you went to a gallery page. The next request goes to your server but the server does not have any idea about your background color preference.

Now if the request contained a cookie telling the server about your preference, the website would serve you your right preference.

Now this is one way. Another way is a session. Think of cookies as information stored on client side. But what if server needs to store some temporary info about you on server side. Info that is maybe too sensitive to be exposed in cookies, which are local and easily intercepted.

Now you would ask, but HTTP is stateless. Correct. But Server could keep info about you in a map, whose is the session id. this session id is set on the client side as a cookie or resent with every request in parameters. Now server is only getting the key but can lookup information about you, like whether you are logged in successfully, what is your role in the system etc.

Wow, that a lot of text, but I hope it helped. If not feel free to ask more.